# Run anaconda python from php but its running default python

Tags: php, python, anaconda

I have anaconda3 python 3.7 inside that I have installed python modules like OpenCV pymongo numpy and more.
When I run python -V in terminal I am getting the output as python Python 3.7.1
but when I Run

```
$out=shell_exec("cd $username/$projectname ; python -V 2>&1");
        echo $out;
```

I am getting Python 2.7.12

I have tried to give anaconda3/bin/python but i am getting permission denied error

```
$out=shell_exec("cd $username/$projectname ; python -V 2>&1");
        echo $out;
```

Comment: You might verify the root directory your php script is calling python from.  Then also make sure $out is getting the correct data.

Answer (score 0):

use python3 instead of python:

```
$out=shell_exec("cd $username/$projectname ; python3 -V 2>&1");
        echo $out;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution instead of python I pointed it to anaconda python here is the code

```
$out=shell_exec("cd $username/$projectname ; anaconda3/bin/python -V 2>&1");
    echo $out;
```

If you want to use specfic environment of anaconda.

```
$out=shell_exec("cd $username/$projectname ; anaconda3/envs/myenv_name/bin/python -V 2>&1");
    echo $out;
```